# NSURLConnection was deprecated in iOS 9, How to fix it

Tags: nsurlconnection

I am getting the issue with:
[image]

Can someone help me How to fix this warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSURLConnection` is deprecated in iOS9 just use `NSURLSession` instead.

In your case it will look approximately as follows:

```
let url = NSURL(string: urlString as String))
var task: NSURLSessionDataTask!
let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
let session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration)
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)

task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    // Your code
})

task.resume()
```

Comment: How should I use. Can u give an example